# if else syntax error in C

Tags: c

```
if(aptr[i] < bptr[i])
     a->used = BI_LESS_THAN;
else
     return BI_GREATER_THAN;
```

I can not figure out why this code will not compile.  It says that it is expecting a '}' before the start of the else.  Is this invalid in C?  I am compiling in Netbeans using GCC.

Comment: the error is not in the snippet included

Comment: It's probably in the surrounding code. That part is fine. The compiler sometimes gives you line numbers that aren't _really_ where the error is. It's just when it found the first inconsistency, so to speak.

Comment: What is your BI_LESS_THAN define?

Comment: What are `BI_LESS_THAN` and `BI_GREATER_THAN`?

Comment: This is why you should always use `{}`

Comment: If your `else` has a `return`, does your `if` need one also?  Hard to say for sure without surrounding code, but certainly a probability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is consistent with your `BI_LESS_THAN` macro being malformed. Before the file is actually compiled, the C preprocessor will substitute `BI_LESS_THAN` with whatever you have defined it to, exactly as it's written. That's why the compiler error seems a little cryptic.

Comment: I accidentally included a semicolon in the macro.

Comment: Yeah, the second semicolon makes an empty statement so there are effectively two statements between `if` and `else`.